# Conditional replacement using if else statement throwing error in R v 4.2.0

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a dataset with a lot of repeating values.

Example of the data structure:

```
  GRID  DATE       TIME  TAGLFT TAGRT COL    LOCX  LOCY  YEAR   TOTAL.sum
  <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
  AG    2004-06-01 09:33 47962  47963 P/-    20.5   0    2004     2
  AG    2004-06-01 09:33 47962  47963 P/-    20.5   0.5  2004     2
```

I am trying to conditionally replace `LOCY` values if the `sum` column for the `group_by` is greater than 1 like so:

```
data %>% 
group_by(GRID, DATE, TIME, TAGLFT, TAGRT, COL, LOCX, YEAR) %>%
    mutate(LOCY=if(TOTAL.sum>1) first(LOCY) else LOCY)
```

Desired output is:

```
  GRID  DATE       TIME  TAGLFT TAGRT COL    LOCX  LOCY  YEAR   TOTAL.sum
  <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
  AG    2004-06-01 09:33 47962  47963 P/-    20.5   0    2004     2
  AG    2004-06-01 09:33 47962  47963 P/-    20.5   0    2004     2
```

The script above was working fine until I updated my R to v 4.2.0.

Now when I run the mutate part of my script, I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `LOCY = if (sum > 1) first(LOCY) else LOCY`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 73: GRID = "AG", DATE = 2004-06-01, TIME = "09:33", TAGLFT = "47962", TAGRT = "47963", COL = "P/-", LOCX = 20.5, YEAR = 2004.
Caused by error in `if (TOTAL.sum > 1) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Any ideas what might be going on here?** Is it a problem with my script? Am I missing something with my syntax?

---

In case it's needed, here is my `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] adehabitatHR_0.4.19 adehabitatLT_0.3.25 CircStats_0.2-6     boot_1.3-28        
 [5] MASS_7.3-57         adehabitatMA_0.3.14 ade4_1.7-19         deldir_1.0-6       
 [9] jpeg_0.1-9          ggmap_3.0.0         RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3 raster_3.5-15      
[13] maps_3.4.0          rgdal_1.5-30        rgeos_0.5-9         maptools_1.1-4     
[17] sp_1.4-7            data.table_1.14.2   sf_1.0-7            spatsoc_0.1.16     
[21] DescTools_0.99.45   glmmTMB_1.1.3       lme4_1.1-29         Matrix_1.4-1       
[25] ggnetwork_0.5.10    scales_1.2.0        cowplot_1.1.1       gridExtra_2.3      
[29] psych_2.2.5         beepr_1.3           here_1.0.1          magrittr_2.0.3     
[33] rcompanion_2.4.15   devtools_2.4.3      usethis_2.1.6       forcats_0.5.1      
[37] stringr_1.4.0       purrr_0.3.4         readr_2.1.2         tibble_3.1.7       
[41] ggplot2_3.3.6       tidyverse_1.3.1     lubridate_1.8.0     tidyr_1.2.0        
[45] plyr_1.8.7          krsp_0.0.2          dplyr_1.0.9        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] readxl_1.4.0        backports_1.4.1     TMB_1.8.1           splines_4.2.0      
  [5] TH.data_1.1-1       fansi_1.0.3         memoise_2.0.1       tzdb_0.3.0         
  [9] remotes_2.4.2       modelr_0.1.8        matrixStats_0.62.0  sandwich_3.0-1     
 [13] prettyunits_1.1.1   colorspace_2.0-3    rvest_1.0.2         haven_2.5.0        
 [17] callr_3.7.0         crayon_1.5.1        jsonlite_1.8.0      libcoin_1.0-9      
 [21] Exact_3.1           keyring_1.3.0       survival_3.3-1      zoo_1.8-10         
 [25] glue_1.6.2          gtable_0.3.0        emmeans_1.7.4-1     pkgbuild_1.3.1     
 [29] mvtnorm_1.1-3       DBI_1.1.2           Rcpp_1.0.8.3        xtable_1.8-4       
 [33] tmvnsim_1.0-2       units_0.8-0         foreign_0.8-82      proxy_0.4-26       
 [37] stats4_4.2.0        httr_1.4.3          modeltools_0.2-23   ellipsis_0.3.2     
 [41] pkgconfig_2.0.3     multcompView_0.1-8  dbplyr_2.1.1        utf8_1.2.2         
 [45] tidyselect_1.1.2    rlang_1.0.2         munsell_0.5.0       cellranger_1.1.0   
 [49] tools_4.2.0         cachem_1.0.6        cli_3.3.0           generics_0.1.2     
 [53] audio_0.1-10        broom_0.8.0         fastmap_1.1.0       processx_3.5.3     
 [57] fs_1.5.2            coin_1.4-2          rootSolve_1.8.2.3   nlme_3.1-157       
 [61] xml2_1.3.3          brio_1.1.3          compiler_4.2.0      rstudioapi_0.13    
 [65] png_0.1-7           e1071_1.7-9         testthat_3.1.4      reprex_2.0.1       
 [69] stringi_1.7.6       ps_1.7.0            desc_1.4.1          lattice_0.20-45    
 [73] classInt_0.4-3      nloptr_2.0.2        vctrs_0.4.1         pillar_1.7.0       
 [77] lifecycle_1.0.1     lmtest_0.9-40       estimability_1.3    bitops_1.0-7       
 [81] lmom_2.8            R6_2.5.1            RMySQL_0.10.23      KernSmooth_2.23-20 
 [85] gld_2.6.4           sessioninfo_1.2.2   codetools_0.2-18    assertthat_0.2.1   
 [89] pkgload_1.2.4       rjson_0.2.21        rprojroot_2.0.3     withr_2.5.0        
 [93] nortest_1.0-4       mnormt_2.0.2        multcomp_1.4-19     expm_0.999-6       
 [97] parallel_4.2.0      hms_1.1.1           terra_1.5-21        grid_4.2.0         
[101] coda_0.19-4         class_7.3-20        minqa_1.2.4         numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
```

Comment: Any chance this is due to the fact that `sum` is also the name of a function?

Comment: Maybe you want `mutate(LOCY=if(first(sum)>1) first(LOCY) else LOCY)`. If you have more than one `sum` value per group, you need to be clear which one you want to use. Or maybe you want `all(sum>1)` or `any(sum>1)`. Not sure what your logic should be.

Comment: I have named it other things (like S, tot, SUM) and the error still persists.

Comment: @MrFlick Your suggestion to use `first(sum)>1` worked. Weird that it ran with no problems in v 4.1.3 without errors. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the vectorized version of `if` which is `ifelse` function as follows:

```r
data %>%
 group_by(GRID, DATE, TIME, TAGLFT, TAGRT, COL, LOCX, YEAR) %>%
 mutate(LOCY = ifelse(sum > 1, first(LOCY) , LOCY))

#>   # A tibble: 2 × 10
# Groups:   GRID, DATE, TIME, TAGLFT, TAGRT, COL, LOCX, YEAR [1]
 GRID  DATE       TIME  TAGLFT TAGRT COL    LOCX  LOCY  YEAR   sum
 <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <int> <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1 AG    2004-06-01 09:33  47962 47963 P/-    20.5     0  2004     2
2 AG    2004-06-01 09:33  47962 47963 P/-    20.5     0  2004     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>